# Spotify Playback SDK: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'togglePlay' of null

Tags: javascript, spotify

I am using the Spotify Playback SDK on my local site. This is my code:

```
window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
    const token = "<?php echo $_SESSION["accessToken"] ?>";
    const player = new Spotify.Player({
    name: 'Spotify Clone',
    getOAuthToken: cb => {
        cb(token);
    }
});
window.player = player;

// Connect to the player!
window.player.connect();

// Error handling
window.player.addListener('initialization_error', ({message}) => {
    console.error(message);
});
window.player.addListener('authentication_error', ({message}) => {
    console.error(message);
});
window.player.addListener('account_error', ({message}) => {
    console.error(message);
});
window.player.addListener('playback_error', ({message}) => {
    console.error(message);
});

// Playback status updates
window.player.addListener('player_state_changed', state => {
    console.log(state);
});

// Ready
window.player.addListener('ready', ({device_id}) => {
    console.log('Ready with Device ID', device_id);
});

// Not Ready
window.player.addListener('not_ready', ({device_id}) => {
    console.log('Device ID has gone offline', device_id);
});

}
document.getElementById("play-arrow").onclick = function () {
    window.player.togglePlay().then(() => {
        console.log('Toggled playback!');
    });
}
```

Everything else is working. For example I can display the current position in the browser. Everything like togglePlay or skip or seek is only working like 10% of the time connecting to the device and I have to reload the page multiple times and connect. This is the error I get:

```
index.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'togglePlay' of null
at h._playbackControl (index.js:9)
at h._onTogglePlay (index.js:9)
at h._handleMessages (index.js:9)
at r._receiveMessage (index.js:9)
```

window.player is not Null, I checked it in the console.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing you copied those event listeners from some sample code. I think you're supposed to replace those `log` statements with custom callback code. For instance, upon receiving `'not_ready'`, you'd probably disable the play button. As it is, if you did watch the console, I bet you'd find a strong correlation between the receiving the `'ready'` event and the player working properly!

Comment: I will try that later thank you. Still the question remains for what reason the player is not ready sometimes. Like I said it's working sometimes without changing the procedure.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm encountering a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue using the Spotify Webplayback SDK in a next.js project.

For me, the issue was having `reactStrictMode: true` in my next.config.js.
If you're using react strict mode, try disabling it.